# Maximizing borderless form with multiple monitors c#

Tags: c#, monitor, maximize, multiple-monitors, borderless

I'm currently making a borderless form with a Doubleclick event to maximize form. But I realized that the form wouldn't maximize on the two other screens, only my main middle.
So my code is currently:

```
private void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((this.Height == Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height) && (this.Width == Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width))
    {
        this.Width = 534;
        this.Height = 600;
        CenterToScreen();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
        this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
        this.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
    }  
}
```

It might look weird, but I use it to not cover the taskbar.
I need a code like this to dock it to the side, and use it to calculate where the form should be. Looking like this: [half right screen dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0hsS.png)
when I click one of those 9 buttons, it will dock the screen in different places of the screen. In corner, half of the screen or in the middle.

I tried using a code where the form would detect which screen it was on, and using that again to maximize the form on that screen, but I got a bunch of red lines, and it didn't work in the end.

I have 3 monitors.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hardcoded it to primary screen, which is the screen with the task bar. To allow other screens get the screen the form is currently on an adjust to that.

```
private void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((this.Height == Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Height) && (this.Width == Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Width))
    {
        this.Width = 534;
        this.Height = 600;
        CenterToScreen();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Height = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Height;
        this.Width = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Width;
        this.Location = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Location;
    }  
}
```

Comment: It worked, I've seen the code before, but I didn't know how to put it in. Thanks